# How an i get product category name from it's id in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a shortcode for my wp+woocommerce site, that will show the name of the current products category. I get the category id from my url with get request - this is a specialty. It will look something like:

```
function this_product_category_name() {
$cat_id = (int) str_replace('-product_cat', '', $_GET['really_curr_tax']);
// here must be a string to get the $cat_name from $cat_id;
echo $cat_name;
}

add_shortcode( 'this_product_category_name', 'this_product_category_name' );
```

What can be the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and provide some feedback, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on the `product category` page, then you could use `get_queried_object`, and then from that object you could get the `name` like so:

```php
$cat = get_queried_object();

echo $cat->name;

//or if you want to get its id 

echo $cat->term_id;

//if you want to see the object and what's in it then you could use print_r()

print_r($cat);
```

Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

So your code would be something like this:

```php
function this_product_category_name() 
{

  $cat = get_queried_object();

  echo $cat->name;

}

add_shortcode( 'this_product_category_name', 'this_product_category_name' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_term_by()`.

```
function this_product_category_name() {
    $cat_id = (int) str_replace('-product_cat', '', $_GET['really_curr_tax']);
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
    echo $product_cat->name;
}
add_shortcode( 'this_product_category_name', 'this_product_category_name' );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [get_term_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)